# MySQL ZERO warnings

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, error-log

I'm getting the error below in my MySQL log file.

```
[Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
```

How do I turn it off? Does turning the error off have an impact on my database?
I'm on MySQL 5.7.14.

My.ini contains this:

```
sql-mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER"
```

Comment: It is warning, not error. To turn it off remove the mode(s) shown from your config file or command line, or add strict mode setting to it. Study [Server SQL Modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html).

Comment: I don't like warnings in my logs :-) Are you telling me to just ignore them?

Comment: No. The parameters must be consistent. Check `SELECT @@sql_mode` for active connection caused warning.

Comment: @@sql_mode gives me this: NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

Comment: As you can see no `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` included. You may add this mode explicitly on the connection level or you can search for a point where strict mode was disables and correct it.

Comment: Alternatively you can disable zero-checking modes... but think carefully. Doing so you in fact allow the data which may be wrong for your app logic, this can produce wrong results looking as correct ones, and it is possible you will not know about it - very unpleasant situation hard in early detection. It is similar to foreign keys remove in the hope that app data consistence check is enough...

Comment: Do I understand it correct if I say that my database has zero dates in it? I know I have date fields which can contain the value NULL, but they are all catched in the programcode. So the main question is: are zero dates equal to NULL? Or do they mean empty values? Sorry for my noob-questions, but I'm kinda new to database administration...

Comment: *Do I understand it correct if I say that my database has zero dates in it?* it MAY contain zeroes in datetime fields. It ALLOWS to insert zero value without error. *are zero dates equal to NULL?* No. `Null` is like 'nobody knows' whereas `0` is specific value. Calculations and compares with `Null` datetime always give Null (treated as False when compare) whereas the same operation with `0` will give some result (maybe True when compare).Exclusion - null-safe compare `<=>`, but its use in datetime compare is rare.

Comment: `0000-00-00` is a "zero date"; the mode prevents storing such.  `2018-03-00` is a "zero in date"; a different mode prevents storing such; in the future, only one mode will control both.  The `[warning]` is to prep you before the upgrade that forces you to make that change.  The warning says nothing about whether you currently have such 'bad' dates in some table.

Comment: Oh, I'm pretty sure i have 0000-00-00 dates in my database. I'm pretty sure 2018-03-00 is not in my database. So will I be unable to save dates with 0000-00-00 in the future? Should I convert them to NULL?

Answer (score 0):

Check on a test system disabling those 3 sql modes. If success, disable them on the real system and you have solved one problem you where going to encounter in the next database update.

Comment: Ok, but between which modes do I choose? I'm reading the Server SQL Modes that Akina suggested, but I'm still puzzled...

Comment: `sql-mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES,,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER"`

Comment: Right, disable them that way :-D But that would be unsafe says Akina as a comment above :)

Comment: I did say "CHECK ON A TEST SYSTEM"